# Calculation of V_E of a PNP transistor

Tags: transistors, pnp

In this circuit, I found out the wrong value for V_E.

I calculated I_B with KVL around the 5V source loop and I got I_B = 2.25E-4 A
then I calculate I_E = (beta + 1)*I_B = 9e-3 A and V_E = 10 - 4k * I_E  = -26, which is wrong according to the solutions of the exercise.

Could someone explain me how to do it or give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: Can you do KVL around this loop 5V --->20k--->Vbe--->4k---10V

Comment: " I found out a wrong value for V_E" -- What value did you come up with and how? Then we can point out your mistake or an invalid assumption you're making.

Comment: @ErikR 
I calculated I_B with KVL around the 5V source loop and I got I_B = 2.25E-4 A
then I calculate I_E = (beta + 1)*I_B = 9e-3 A and V_E = 10 - 4k * I_E  = -26 which does not make any sense

Comment: How exactly did you get  \$I_B = 2.25E-4 \: [A]= 225 \mu A\$

Comment: @G36 I used the wrong loop, I consider the collector, emitter as a npn. I see...
I will follow your suggestion. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So, did you manage to find the correct answer?

Comment: @G36 Yes, V_E = 6 V
Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: BTW 0.5 V for Veb is incorrect assumption given for this example when Ic=1mA, |Vbe|~ 0.60V